# Check username and password Hibernate in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

I am trying to compare username and password from user with the one in database. I can successfully check the username but I am not sure how to go about comparing username and password at the same time :/ hopefully someone can help me on this

Here is the login method.

```
@ButtonMethod(buttonName="loginButton")
public String loginMethod() {
String address = "login.jsp";
fillBeanFromRequest(data);
setErrors(data);
if (isValidProperty("username") && isValidProperty("password")) {
  Object dataPersistent = 
    HibernateHelper.getFirstMatch(data, 
      "username", data.getUsername());
  if (dataPersistent != null) {
    data = (RequestDataAccount)dataPersistent;
    response.addCookie(new Cookie("username", data.getUsername()));
    clearErrors();
    address = "ShowCookies.jsp";

  }
} else {
  address = "login.jsp";
}
return jspLocation(address);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked, in Java you can compare Strings like this

```
form.getPassword().equals(account.getPassword())
```

but in your code I see you have a `data` variable that at the beginning of the snippet carries the form, and then is assigned the value of a database record! No no. You need both.

Also, since this is a public forum and someone else may come here and see this post, consider the usual rules for password authentication:

- normalize the username before searching a match (at least case-insensitive)
- don't store the password in clear text in the database (use bcrypt for example)
- use a constant-time algorithm when comparing secrets